# Tic Tac Toe Button Press Creates ANR keyDispatchedTimedOut

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I made a one player tic tac toe game recently and I am using an easy AI that randomly places Os. I get an ANR when the last button i press should make the game a draw but the game freezes and stops responding.

These are my ANR errors:

```
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): ANR in g.icstictactoe (g.icstictactoe/.OnePlayer)
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): Load: 0.81 / 0.33 / 0.25
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): CPU usage from 19103ms to 0ms ago:
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):   98% 677/g.icstictactoe: 98% user + 0% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):   0.1% 63/system_server: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 5 minor
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):   0% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): 100% TOTAL: 99% user + 0.1% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): CPU usage from 1156ms to 1716ms later:
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):   91% 677/g.icstictactoe: 91% user + 0% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):     89% 677/g.icstictactoe: 89% user + 0% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):   8.9% 63/system_server: 7.1% user + 1.7% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63):     7.1% 93/InputDispatcher: 5.3% user + 1.7% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.894: E/ActivityManager(63): 100% TOTAL: 98% user + 1.7% kernel
06-28 16:01:25.914: I/InputDispatcher(63): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
06-28 16:01:48.365: W/ActivityManager(63):   Force finishing activity g.icstictactoe/.OnePlayer
06-28 16:01:48.395: I/ActivityManager(63): Killing g.icstictactoe (pid=677): user's request
06-28 16:01:48.395: I/Process(63): Sending signal. PID: 677 SIG: 9
06-28 16:01:48.465: I/ActivityManager(63): Process g.icstictactoe (pid 677) has died.
```

and this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tictactoe);
    count = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    ticTacToe = new Button[3][3];
    ticTacToe[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.top_left);
    ticTacToe[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.top);
    ticTacToe[0][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.top_right);
    ticTacToe[1][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
    ticTacToe[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.center);
    ticTacToe[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
    ticTacToe[2][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottom_left);
    ticTacToe[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    ticTacToe[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottom_right);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    playagain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playagain);
    for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToe.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ticTacToe[0].length; j++)
            ticTacToe[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
    playagain.setOnClickListener(this);
    result.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.top_left: findAnswer(0, 0);
        break;
    case R.id.top: findAnswer(0, 1);
        break;
    case R.id.top_right: findAnswer(0, 2);
        break;
    case R.id.left: findAnswer(1, 0);
        break;
    case R.id.center: findAnswer(1, 1);
        break;
    case R.id.right: findAnswer(1, 2);
        break;
    case R.id.bottom_left: findAnswer(2, 0);
        break;
    case R.id.bottom: findAnswer(2, 1);
        break;
    case R.id.bottom_right: findAnswer(2, 2);
        break;
    case R.id.playagain: playagain();
        break;
    }
}

public void findAnswer(int row, int col) {
    String level = "EASY";
    if(level.equals(EASY))
        easyAnswer(row, col);
}

public void easyAnswer(int row, int col)
{
    ticTacToe[row][col].setText("X");
    ticTacToe[row][col].setClickable(false);
    if (!winOrDraw()) { // If X did not win
        int rowO = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        int colO = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        while (!ticTacToe[rowO][colO].isClickable()) 
        {
            rowO = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            colO = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        ticTacToe[rowO][colO].setText("O");
        ticTacToe[rowO][colO].setClickable(false);
    }
    if(!gameOver)
        winOrDraw();
}

public boolean winOrDraw()
{
    if (checkGame("X")) {
        gameOver = true;
        result.setText("Game Over! X Wins!");
        disableGame();
    } else {
        if (checkGame("O")) {
            gameOver = true;
            result.setText("Game Over! O Wins!");
            disableGame();
        }
    }
    count++;
    if (count == 10 && !gameOver)
    {
        result.setText("This game is a draw!");
        gameOver = true;
    }
    return gameOver;
}

public boolean checkGame(String player) {
    // Horizontal
    if (ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[0][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[0][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else if (ticTacToe[1][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[1][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[1][0].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else if (ticTacToe[2][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[2][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[2][0].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    // Vertical
    else if (ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][0].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][0].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else if (ticTacToe[0][1].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][1].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][1].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else if (ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    // Diagonal
    else if (ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][2].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][0].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else if (ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(ticTacToe[1][1].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(ticTacToe[2][0].getText())
            && ticTacToe[0][2].getText().equals(player))
        return true;
    else {
        result.setText("The game continues...");
        return false;
    }
}
public void playagain() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToe.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ticTacToe[0].length; j++) {
            ticTacToe[i][j].setClickable(true);
            ticTacToe[i][j].setText("");
        }
    result.setText("Click a button to start game");
    count = 0;
    gameOver = false;
}
public void disableGame() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToe.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ticTacToe[0].length; j++)
            ticTacToe[i][j].setClickable(false);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978964/anr-keydispatchingtimedout

Comment: You should use a debugger or logging to find the point where it hangs. My "prime suspect" would be the `while (!ticTacToe[rowO][colO].isClickable())` loop in `easyAnswer()`

Comment: @MichaelButscher the code never reaches that loop because player X is the one causing the ANR. The button press freezes the app before the ticTacToe[row][col].setText("X"); occurs.

Comment: @Gaurav Have you checked this with a debugger or do you only assume this because you don't see the "X"? In the latter case your assumption may be wrong

Comment: @MichaelButscher That was just my assumption, I can debug it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your winOrDraw check does not work as expected, it won't detect the draw condition and your app gets stuck in the while loop that randomly picks a space and checks if it's empty. There are no empty (clickable) spaces when the game ends in draw, so that while loop is an infinite loop and blocks the main thread, hence the ANR.

I bet your error is checking if count == 10 to declare a draw when there's no winner, it should be 9, shouldn't be?